# ListenableFuture callback execution order

Tags: java, parallel-processing, java-7, guava

Guava's `ListenableFuture` library provides a mechanism for adding callbacks to future tasks. This is done as follows:

```
ListenableFuture<MyClass> future = myExecutor.submit(myCallable);
Futures.addCallback(future, new FutureCallback<MyClass>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(@Nullable MyClass myClass) {
      doSomething(myClass);
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
      printWarning(t);
    }}, myCallbackExecutor);
}
```

You can wait for a `ListenableFuture` to complete by calling its `get` function. For instance:

```
MyClass myClass = future.get();
```

My question is, are all callbacks for a certain future guaranteed to run before the `get` terminates. I.e. if there is a future with many callbacks on many callback executors registered, will all the callbacks complete before `get` returns?

**Edit**

My use case is, I pass a builder around to many classes. Each class populates one field of the builder. I want all fields to be populated asynchronously because each field requires an external query to generate the data for the field. I want the user who calls my `asyncPopulateBuilder` to receive a `Future` on which she can call `get` and be assured that all the fields have been populated. The way I thought to do it is as follows:

```
final Builder b;
ListenableFuture<MyClass> future = myExecutor.submit(myCallable);
Futures.addCallback(future, new FutureCallback<MyClass>() {
  @Override
  public void onSuccess(@Nullable MyClass myClass) {
    b.setMyClass(myClass);
  }

  @Override
  public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
    printWarning(t);
  }}, myCallbackExecutor);
}
// Do the same thing for all other fields.
```

What is the recommended way to block until all fields are populated in such a case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Callbacks are not guaranteed to run before `get` returns. More on that below.

As for how to address this use case, I would suggest turning the query for each field's data into a separate `Future`, combining them with `allAsList`+`transform`, and taking action on that. (We may someday provide [a shortcut for the "combine" step](https://github.com/google/guava/issues/1421).)

```
ListenableFuture<MyClass> future = myExecutor.submit(myCallable);

final ListenableFuture<Foo> foo =
    Futures.transform(
        future,
        new Function<MyClass, Foo>() { ... },
        myCallbackExecutor);
final ListenableFuture<Bar> bar = ...;
final ListenableFuture<Baz> baz = ...;

ListenableFuture<?> allAvailable = Futures.allAsList(foo, bar, baz);
ListenableFuture<?> allSet = Futures.transform(
    allAvailable, 
    new Function<Object, Object>() {
      @Override
      public Object apply(Object ignored) {
        // Use getUnchecked, since we know they already succeeded:
        builder.setFoo(Futures.getUnchecked(foo));
        builder.setFoo(Futures.getUnchecked(bar));
        builder.setFoo(Futures.getUnchecked(baz));
        return null;
      }
    }
};
```

Now the user can call `allSet.get()` to await population.

(Or maybe you want for `allSet` to be a `Future<Builder>` so that the user is handed a reference to the builder. Or maybe you don't need a full-on `Future` at all, only a `CountDownLatch`, in which you could use `addCallback` instead of `transform` and count down the latch at the end of the callback.)

This approach may also simplify error handling.

---

RE: "Do callbacks run before `get`?"

First, I am pretty sure that we don't guarantee this anywhere in the spec, so thanks for asking rather than just going for it :) If you do end up wanting to rely on some behavior of the current implementation, please [file an issue](https://github.com/google/guava/issues/new) so that we can add documentation and tests.

Second, if I take your question very literally, what you're asking for isn't possible: If `get()` waits for all listeners to complete, then any listener that calls `get()` will hang!

A slightly more lenient version of your question is "Will all the listeners at least *start* before `get()` returns?" This turns out to be impossible, too: Suppose that I attach two listeners to the same `Future` to be run with `directExecutor()`. Both listeners simply call `get()` and return. One of the listeners has to run first. When it calls `get()`, it will hang, since the second listener hasn't started yet -- nor can it until the first listener is done. (More generally, it can be dangerous to rely on any given `Executor` to execute a task promptly.)

A still more lenient version is "Will the `Future` at least call `submit()` for each of the listeners before `get()` returns?" But this ends up with a problem in the same scenario as I just described: Calling `submit(firstListener)` on a `directExecutor()` runs the task and calls `get()`, which can't complete until the second listener is started, which can't happen until the first listener completes.

If anything, it's starting to sound much more likely that `get()` will return *before* any listeners execute. But thanks to the unpredictability of thread scheduling, we can't rely on that, either. (And again: It's not documented, so please don't rely on it unless you ask for it to be documented!)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! In this case is there any way to register a callback for the completion of all callbacks on a certain future? I will edit the question with my use case.

Comment: @BenjyKessler: One option might be to create a `CountDownLatch` and have each callback count down the latch after doing its work. Another thread can `await` on the latch, knowing that when `await` unblocks successfully, all fields have been set.

Answer (score 0):

```
final Builder b;
CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
ListenableFuture<MyClass> future = myExecutor.submit(myCallable);

Futures.addCallback(future, new FutureCallback<MyClass>() {
 @Override
 public void onSuccess(@Nullable MyClass myClass) {
 b.setMyClass(myClass);
 latch.countDown();
}
 @Override
 public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
 printWarning(t);
 latch.countDown();
}, myCallbackExecutor);

try {
        latch.await();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        LOG.error("something InterruptedException", e);
    } finally {
        myCallbackExecutor.shutdown();
    }
```

**Edit**

code is inspired by @Chris Povirk

> (Or maybe you want for allSet to be a Future so that the user is handed a reference to the builder. Or maybe you don't need a full-on Future at all, only a CountDownLatch, in which you could use addCallback instead of transform and count down the latch at the end of the callback.)
>   This approach may also simplify error handling.

Comment: You can improve you answer by providing an explanation of how your example solves the OPs problem. [Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: just add some.you may ask me questions.